# Using tidyverse to group and summarise the coefficient of variation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with daily precipitation for months between the years 1997-2016. Here is an example:

```
 df<- data.frame(year= as.character(c("1997", "1997","1997","1997","1997","1997","1998","1998","1998")),month= as.character(c("1", "1","1","2","2","2","1","1","1")),cont_month= as.character(c("1", "1","1","2","2","2","13","13","13")),precip= as.numeric(c(5, 2,4,5,6,2,1,3,7)))
```

I want to calculate the coefficient of variation for daily precipitation for each `Cont_Month` subset. I am using the function `cv()` using the  `library(raster)` package.  The new data frame should look like this:

```
 output<- data.frame(year= as.character(c("1997", 
 "1997","1998")),month= as.character(c("1", "2","1")),cont_month= 
 as.character(c("1", "2","13")),cv= as.numeric(c(41.6, 48.03,83.31))
```

I am having trouble with the code below, it is not successfully grouping the daily `precip` by the `cont_month` variable. Instead the same value is repeated in the `precip` column. Any idea what my error is?

```
output<- 
df %>%
 group_by(year, month,cont_month)%>%
  summarise(cv= cv(df$precip))
```

Comment: Don't use `$` - just call `summarise(cv= cv(precip))` - that's the whole point of piping, so you don't have to keep referencing the source object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

out <- 
   df %>%
   group_by(year, month,cont_month)%>%
   summarise(cv= cv(precip))

out
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   year, month [?]
    year  month cont_month       cv
  <fctr> <fctr>     <fctr>    <dbl>
1   1997      1          1 41.65978
2   1997      2          2 48.03845
3   1998      1         13 83.31956
```

When you really need to refer to a dataframe, you can use `.`, for instance as in `summarise(cv= cv(.$precip))`, though here you do not need this. This is more relevant for functions that take `data` as an argument (e.g. `lm`, whose first argument is not the dataframe).

To prevent this issue from emerging in the future, it might be useful to understand what happened: in your call to summarise, you have referred to `df$precip`, and hence the function `cv` uses exactly what you provided as an input, namely the entire vector `df$precip`, as opposed to the group-wise elements of it.